# Problem when integrate caching with concat operator in Rx java

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

Implemented Caching by the following link:
 https://blog.mindorks.com/implement-caching-in-android-using-rxjava-operators

```
fun getSavedAddressList(): Maybe<List<SavedAddress>?>? {
    return Observable.concat(
            getAddressListMemory(),
            getAddressListDatabase(),
            getAddressListNetwork()).firstElement()
}

   fun getAddressListDatabase(): Observable<List<SavedAddress>?> {
        return Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe { emitter: ObservableEmitter<List<SavedAddress>?> ->
            val list: ArrayList<SavedAddress> = addressDao.getAddressList() as ArrayList<SavedAddress>
            if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                emitter.onNext(list)
            }
            emitter.onComplete()
            if (list.isNotEmpty())


    getAddressListNetwork().subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())?.observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())?.subscribe()
        })
    }
```

items in the database are retrieving perfectly after storing into database

problem is network calling is not happening after getting a list from database

I want to get three data source sequentially one after another and store latest data in the database

Comment: make sure that `getAddressListDatabase()` calls `onComplete()`, otherwise `concat` doesn't switch to next Observable

Comment: @borichellow updated my code

Comment: what is the purpose of last line `getAddressListNetwork().subscribeOn()...`? Why do you need it?

Comment: @borichellow after getting data from database calling getAddressListNetwork after a successful response im storing new data to db

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're leaking the `getAddressListNetwork` `Disposable` in there because you are trying to do too much inside the `getAddressListDatabase`.

I think what you want is this:

```
fun getSavedAddressList(): Observable<List<SavedAddress>> {
    return Observable.concat(
            getAddressListMemory(),
            getAddressListDatabase(),
            getAddressListNetwork()).distinctUntilChanged())
}
```

This will always try to fetch the addresses from the 3 sources, and only emitting if the data is different than the previous emission, meaning the data is "fresher".

To be honest with you, I think you need to have a look at the concept of "stale data" and "cache invalidation".